# In SPO list why would FilterFieldX/FilterValueX work while FilterName/FilterMultiValue is ignored?

Tags: filter, sharepoint-list, sharepoint-list-filter, sp-online, filtermulivalue

I am using a custom list with standard OOB AllItems.aspx view using the modern experience. (**NOT a web-part, NOT the classic experience**)

When I filter using

```
.../AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=MyTextColumn&FilterValue1=MyVal
```

it works fine and I see only rows containing MyVal.

When I filter using

```
.../AllItems.aspx?FilterName=MyTextColumn&FilterMultiValue=MyVal
```

or

```
.../AllItems.aspx?FilterName=MyTextColumn&FilterMultiValue=MyVal;YourVal
```

The list view acts as if no filtering was applied - all rows are displayed.

Ultimately the column I want to select on is "Single Line of Text" but I have gotten the same results using "Choice" and "Person or Group" and "Yes/No" as well. They work fine with FilterField1/FilterValue and they ignore FilterName/FilterMultiValue.

- Is there some special configuration I have to do for SPO to allow for
  filtering by multi-values?
- Is this a feature that works only with
  list web-parts and not with standard list views?
- Is this a feature
  that is no longer supported? (Most of the references I've read are
  from 2010-2014)...
- Am I mistaken in my understanding of how this
  should work? Should I be able to directly replace
  FilterField1/FilterValue1 with FilterName/FilterMultiValue and have
  it work identically?

I have checked about 20 times to make sure I have correct case and spelling on FilterName/FilterMultiValue and I have even tried (as I've seen on a couple sites) FilterField1/FilterMultiValue1 and various other permutations.

Perhaps unrelated but FilterOpX is being ignored as well. I saw several comments that this was a difficult-to-reproduce problem that occurred on some sites/lists and not on others...

Comment: What is the data type of your Column/field?

Comment: Ultimately I want to apply it to a "Single Line of Text". When that didn't work I tried it on some other types (most recent a "People") and get the same result where FilterField1 works but FilterName is ignored.

Comment: Added my answer below. I can't mark it as the right answer because stackexchange doesn't trust me on the sharepoint site, but you can still view it.

Comment: If someone comes up with a solution how to use FilterMultiValue (with * as wildcard) I'm still very interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apparently the

```
useFiltersInViewXml=1
```

query parameter is a thing. Maybe just in SPO or maybe just in Modern Experience. I'm finding ZIP in terms of documentation from M$, but when I add that into my query:

```
.../AllItems.aspx?FilterName=MyTextColumn&FilterMultiValue=MyVal;YourVal&useFiltersInViewXml=1
```

then all of a sudden the world is my oyster...

Hope this helps someone else. If someone sees someplace where this is decently documented please comment below.

**---EDIT---**

My oyster ended up without a pearl. It works beautifully at first but some random number of seconds after that SPO does a reload via AJAX which ignores the filters I have specified.

**TRY AGAIN:**

This time I went into the unfiltered view, filtered by the columns I'm interested in, and reverse engineered the resulting URL. I end up with a query that looks like this:

```
.../AllItems.aspx?FilterFields1=MyTextColumn&FilterValues1=MyVal%3B%23YourVal&FilterTypes1=Text
```

Note that I have changed the URL as follows:

- `FilterFields1` instead of `FilterName`
- `FilterValues1` instead of `FilterMultiValue`
- separating my multi-values with `%3B%23` (which is `;#` encoded)
- added the `FilterTypes1=Text` query parameter for this "Single Line of Text" column type
- no longer using `useFiltersInViewXml=1`

Some "Gotchas" to be aware of:

- If your dynamic query sometimes allows multi-values and other times has only a single value you must change your URL (`FilterField1` and `FilterValue1` without the s)
- `FilterTypes1=Text` will change based on column type - manually filter and examine the resulting URL to figure out what you need
- While `FilterName`/`FilterMultiValue` supported (or was supposed to support) `*` as a wildcard, this is not supported here with this syntax
- I'm testing this only on Sharepoint Online as of Aug-2019 - YMMV elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Filter in below format:

```
.../AllItems.aspx?FilterFields1=MyTextColumn-FilterValues1=MyVal;#YourVal
```

Note **;#** as a separator between two values.

Comment: As soon as I put myval;#yourval in the URL then it redirects to a simple AllItems.aspx URL without any query parameters at all. In other words, it redirects to a URL without the ? or the & or any of those Filternnn values. I am familiar with using ";#" as a separator between the ID and the label in a person or metadata field; if that is what you were attempting to do that is NOT what my question is about.